# In vim, how do I go back to where I was before a search?

Tags: vim, vi

Programming in vim I often go search for something, yank it, then go back to where I was, insert it, modify it.

The problem is that after I search and find, I need to MANUALLY find my way back to where I was.

Is there an automatic way to go back to where I was when I initiated my last search?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move cursor to its last position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052079/move-cursor-to-its-last-position)

Answer (score 449, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> takes me to the previous location. Don't know about location before the search.

Edit: Also, <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> will take you to the last change you made.

Comment: It also appears that pressing CTRL+O enough times will also start taking you back through previously opened files.

Comment: Ctrl+O is my preferred method also.  I use it constantly and wish other editors replicated its behavior.

Comment: Yes, CTRL-O and CTRL-I seem to take you back and forth where you've been, nice.

Comment: With CTags, Ctrl+T will take you back... don't know how it is different from Ctrl+O.

Comment: Ctrl+T will only take you back if you got there using a tag.  If you searched it without using tags Ctrl+T will take you back to the place you were before you searched for your last *tag*

Comment: I've found that if I jump vía `:70` and then `:100`, pressing `ctrl+o` once goes back to the original location, *not* line 70. :(

Comment: @Hugo read `:h up-down-motions`, where it states about `:[range]` that “in contrast with G this command does not modify the jumplist.”

Answer (score 103):

Use ``` `` ``` to jump back to the exact position you were in before you searched/jumped, or `''` to jump back to the start of the line you were on before you searched/jumped.

Comment: Only sees to work if you are on the first match, `n`-ing to subsequent matches means you do not jump back to where you started.

Comment: What if you searched and made a change?

Comment: You can also use `g;` and `g,`, it goes to the position of the previous/next change.

Answer (score 48):

I've always done by it setting a mark.

1. In command-mode, press **<kbd>m</kbd>*[letter]***.  For example, <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> sets a mark at the current line using **a** as the mark identifier.
2. To get back to the mark press **<kbd>'</kbd> [letter]**.  For example, <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> takes you back to the line mark set in step 1.  To get back to the column position of the row where you marked the line, use <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (**back-tick *[letter]***).

To see all of the marks that currently set, type **`:marks`**.

---

On a slightly unrelated note, I just discovered another nifty thing about marks.

Let's say you jump to mark **b** by doing <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>.  Vim automatically sets the mark <kbd>'</kbd> (that's a single-quote) to be whichever line you were on before jumping to mark **b**.

That means you can do <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to jump to that mark, then do <kbd>''</kbd> (2 single-quotes) to jump back to wherever you were before.

I discovered this accidentally using the `:marks` command, which shows a list of all marks.

Comment: luckily a mark is often unnecessary since vim keeps special track of some positions and gives you access to them with ``, ^O, etc.

Comment: the mark only seems to take me to the beginning of the line on which it was set. ):

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson You may have figured this out by now, but while using ' will take you to the marked line, ` will take you to the exact location.

Answer (score 44):

You really should read `:help jumplist` it explains all of this very well.

Comment: I like this answer the best, there's a LOT of info in :help that most people don't know about (and I didn't until recently)

Comment: What a great read! This is super helpful. <C-o> and <C-i> to cycle through places you've recently been. Works across buffers by default : )

Comment: Thank you for providing the root answer - using the jargon "jumplist" and pointing to the extremely helpful documentation. I had no idea this was the paradigm used.

Answer (score 40):

<kbd>CTRL+O</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+I</kbd>, for jumping back and forward.

Answer (score 8):

I use this one:

```
nnoremap / ms/
nnoremap ? ms?
```

Then if I search something by using `/` or `?`, I can go back quickly by `` `s ``. You could replace the letter `s` to any letter you like.

Comment: Only caveat here is it breaks searching in a window such as NerdTree where `m` is defined to be something other than mark, in the case of NerdTree it is menu.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is to set a mark, with `m[letter]`, then go back to it with `'[letter]`

Comment: It's a treat to see you when I search for vim tips.  I've been using ctrl-o more along with ctrl-i because it steps back and forth easier and more automatically.