# Jump to function definition

Tags: function, vim

How can I jump to a function definition using Vim? For example with Visual Assist, I can type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> under a function and it opens a context menu listing the files with definitions.

How can I do something like this in vim?

Comment: gnu global is better than ctags.

Comment: @Jichao, can you give us a little more insight about your experience? With what languages did gnu global work better for you? Is there anything else about the context you preferred it in that me be important? Or perhaps you have used it in many different scenarios and you seem to mostly/always prefer it? What do you like about it better? Thanks.

Comment: @Jichao I turned your comment into a community wiki answer. I would welcome your changes and input for this answer.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

Use ctags.  Generate a tags file, and tell vim where it is using the :tags command.  Then you can just jump to the function definition using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>

There are more tags tricks and tips in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vimctags-tips-and-tricks).

Comment: Will this work for PHP? I forgot to mention that I need it to work with C,C++,php and python.

Comment: php is C-like enough that "Exuberant ctags" should work with it.  Don't know if it has a python mode.

Comment: No experience with Cscope.  What is is?

Comment: The similarity to C has nothing to do with CTags support PHP. It supports PHP as well as Python. Have a look at http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html to see the full support.

Comment: @dwayne, with the program `ctags` from ctags.sourceforge.net.

Comment: it would be great to get a reference to where it is best to learn how to operate those ctags.

Comment: if you use Ctrl-] and then Ctrl t -- you will return to previous location

Comment: if C-] is not working, then try to generate tags file:
using following command :
`ctags -R .`

Comment: remember that when using ctags with vim, then open file from scope where tag file is generated, otherwise ctrl-] will not work

Comment: This works out of the box in Android Studio/IdeaVim.

Comment: This is obsolete. Current solution is to use one of the LSP clients availabe for `vim` and `nvim` as plugins in conjunction with a dedicated standalone language server that analyses your code in real time. There are many LSP servers, e.g. Eclipse.JDT.ls for Java, felixfbecker/php-language-server for PHP and more.

Comment: Actually it's not the real `jump to definition`. It just jumps to the location where it has the same symbol under the cursor, whereas the real `jump to definition` such as the one in IDE, is go to the definition of function or variable within **current class**, even though other classes have same function or variables.

Comment: @cprn disagree. Tags support is still quite easy; no need to fire up a whole language server. I use tags for all my projects with a custom git hook.

Comment: I guess it depends on tags generator. Last time I was using a PHP specific fork of `ctags` it didn't support namespaces, does it now? Still, all the servers I worked with (at least those in C) were very fast and easy to communicate with through sockets, all that while rarely using more than few megabytes of RAM. Given the other benefits querying one every few key strokes hardly seems excessive.

Comment: @LewisChan What you mean is namespace-aware jump-to-definition and yes, that's what intellisense gives you. Try CoC - I have the answer in this thread that describes how to use it.

Answer (score 205):

If everything is contained in one file, there's the command **`gd`** (as in 'goto definition'), which will take you to the first occurrence in the file of the word under the cursor, which is often the definition.

Comment: what if I don't have the word under the cursor (I'd rather type it)?

Comment: @FuadSaud just search for it using `/`

Comment: `/` is almost always not precise, as it's going to match all ocurrences. I found out you can actually do `:tag <function_name>` to jump to the definition via ctags.

Comment: @Faud Jump To Definition feature relies on pointing an identifier with a cursor (in every IDE). Typing/searching is another feature, you're confusing them.

Comment: Beautiful. And it even traverses files within IdeaVIM (free plugin for IntelliJ tools, such as CLion).

Comment: How do you get back to where you were after you have done `gd`?

Comment: @gloriphobia `Ctrl`+`o` to go back; `Ctrl`+`i` to go forward

Answer (score 131):

<kbd>g*</kbd> does a decent job without ctags being set up.

That is, type <kbd>g</kbd>,<kbd>*</kbd> (or just <kbd>*</kbd> - see below) to search for the word under the cursor (in this case, the function name). Then press <kbd>n</kbd> to go to the next (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> for previous) occurrence.

It doesn't jump directly to the definition, given that this command just searches for the word under the cursor, but if you don't want to deal with setting up ctags at the moment, you can at least save yourself from having to re-type the function name to search for its definition.

--Edit--
Although I've been using g* for a long time, I've recently discovered two shortcuts for these shortcuts!

(a) <kbd>*</kbd> will jump to the next occurrence of the word under the cursor. (No need to type the `g`, the 'goto' command in vi).

(b) <kbd>#</kbd> goes to the previous occurrence, in similar fashion.

N and n still work, but '#' is often very useful to start the search initially in the reverse direction, for example, when looking for the declaration of a variable under the cursor.

Comment: The difference between `*` and `g*` is word boundaries on the search. `*` does a `\<keyword\>` search (same as `\bkeyword\b` in regular regex), while `g*` searches for `keyword` without word boundaries.

Comment: if you have a hundred occurrences of a function in a file, `*` is going to take you on average 50 hits before you find the definition.

Comment: @naught101, but if you have two occurrences of the function, `*` is going to take on average only one hit to find the definition.  Unless you do  `*` _on_ the definition, at which point you should probably be taking a short break...

Answer (score 74):

Use `gd` or `gD` while placing the cursor on any variable in your program.

1. `gd` will take you to the local declaration.
2. `gD` will take you to the global declaration.

more navigation options can be found in [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Go_to_definition_using_g).

Use [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html) for cross referencing large project such as the linux kernel.

Comment: The question is about jumping to the "definition" and not "declaration". If function is declared in a header file e.g. `test.h` <key>g</key>+<key>d</key> will take you to the "declaration". Once there there is no way to jump to the "definition" that is inside "test.c"...

Is there any way to do this jump using COC? @cpm answered some things, but did not explain this jump.

Comment: I don't know any other way as to use `ctags -R *` in terminal *(inside project folder)* and then inside vim issue command `:tag <searched tag>`. After so many years this is still not implemented... I am so dissapointed...

Comment: @71GA You didn't ask under my answer :) `nmap <silent> gD <Plug>(coc-implementation)` should bind what you want to `gD`.

Answer (score 69):

**TL;DR:**

You *can* do this using internal VIM functionality but a modern (and much easier) way in classic VIM is to use [COC](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) for easy installation of add-ons and triggering auto completion and one or more [language servers](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) (LS) for jump-to-definition (and way way more). For even more functionality (but it's not needed for jump-to-definition) you can install one or more [debuggers](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/) and get a full-blown IDE experience.

Best second is to use native VIM's functionality called `define-search` but it was invented for C preprocessor's `#define` directive and for most other languages requires extra configuration, for some isn't possible at all (also you miss on other IDE features). Finally, a fallback to that is `ctags` or (IMHO better) [GNU global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/).

Everything from this post is applicable to both VIM and NeoVIM, however, if you're actually using NeoVIM then I highly recommend following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stqUbv-5u2s) on how to create your `init.lua` config instead with a fully usable example and each line explained - it'll give you a noticeably faster IDE experience but unfortunately won't work in classic VIM.

**Quick-start:**

1. install [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) to manage your VIM plug-ins
2. add [COC](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and (optionally) [Vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector) at the top of `~/.vimrc`:

   ```
   call plug#begin()
   Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
   Plug 'puremourning/vimspector'
   call plug#end()

   " key mappings example
   nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
   nmap <silent> gD <Plug>(coc-implementation)
   nmap <silent> gr <Plug>(coc-references)
   " there's way more, see `:help coc-key-mappings@en'
   ```
3. call `:source $MYVIMRC | PlugInstall` to reload VIM config and download plug-ins
4. restart `vim` and call `:CocInstall coc-marketplace` to get easy access to COC extensions
5. call `:CocList marketplace` and search for language servers, e.g.:

- type `python` to find `coc-jedi`,
- type `php` to find `coc-phpls`, etc.

6. (optionally) see `:h VimspectorInstall` to install additional debuggers, e.g.:

- `:VimspectorInstall debugpy`,
- `:VimspectorInstall vscode-php-debug`, etc.

**Full story:**

[Language server](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) (LS) is a separate standalone application (one for each programming language) that runs in the background and analyses your whole project in real time exposing extra capabilities to your editor (any editor, not only `vim`). You get things like:

- namespace aware tag completion
- jump to definition
- jump to next / previous error
- find all references to an object
- find all interface implementations
- rename across a whole project
- documentation on hover
- snippets, code actions, formatting, linting and more...

Communication with language servers takes place via [Language Server Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) (LSP). Both [`nvim`](https://neovim.io/) and `vim8` (or higher) support LSP through plug-ins, the most popular being [Conquer of Completion](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) (COC).

List of actively developed language servers and their capabilities is available on [Lang Server](https://langserver.org/) website. Not all of those are provided by COC extensions. If you want to use one of those you can either write a COC extension yourself or install LS manually and use the combo of following VIM plug-ins as alternative to COC:

- [LanguageClient](https://github.com/autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim) - handles LSP
- [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) - triggers completion as you type

Communication with debuggers takes place via [Debug Adapter Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/) (DAP). The most popular DAP plug-in for VIM is [Vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector).

[Language Server Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) (LSP) was created by **Microsoft** for Visual Studio Code and released as an **open source project** with a permissive MIT license (standardized by collaboration with Red Hat and Codenvy). Later on Microsoft released [Debug Adapter Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/) (DAP) as well. Any language supported by VSCode is supported in VIM.

For classic VIM I personally recommend using COC + language servers provided by COC extensions + [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) for extra linting (but with LSP support disabled to avoid conflicts with COC) + [Vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector) + debuggers provided by Vimspector (called "gadgets") + the following VIM plug-ins:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim'
Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
Plug 'puremourning/vimspector'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'yggdroot/indentline'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'kana/vim-textobj-user'
  \| Plug 'glts/vim-textobj-comment'
Plug 'janko/vim-test'
Plug 'vim-scripts/vcscommand.vim'
Plug 'mhinz/vim-signify'
call plug#end()
```

You can google each to see what they do.

**Native VIM jump to definition:**

If you really don't want to use Language Server and still want a somewhat decent jump to definition with native VIM functionality you should get familiar with `:ij` and `:dj` which stand for `include-jump` and `definition-jump`. These VIM commands let you jump to any file that's included by your project or jump to any defined symbol that's in any of the included files. For that to work, however, VIM has to know how lines that include files or define symbols look like in any given language you code in. You can set it up per language in `~/.vim/ftplugin/$file_type.vim` with `set include=$regex` and `set define=$regex` patterns as described in `:h include-search`, although, coming up with those patterns is a bit of an art and sometimes not possible at all, e.g. for languages where symbol definition or file import can span over multiple lines (e.g. Golang). If that's your case the usual fallback is `ctags` as described in other answers or [global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/) which is more popular in Emacs community and will require some fiddling on your own to run with VIM (but IMHO is worth it).

Comment: coc doesn't seem to offer a way to jump to a function definition by searching though right? i.e. if I know a function name, can I use coc to jump to it from anywhere?

Comment: Coc supports its own type of extensions and comes with some - among others there's a `symbols list` extension. It's mapped to `<space>s` by default (at least I think it is - if not, just type `:CocList symbols`). When the list triggers you get an input to search for a variable, function, class, interface, whatever.

Comment: Side note: `symbols list` doesn't support fuzzy search (or idk how to configure it) so I often find myself using `files list` instead (at least for classes and interfaces). The most common listing plugins are in: `:CocInstall coc-lists`.

Comment: I wish I had seen this answer before I started hitting my head against a wall to configure Neovim! +1. Could you tell me what you think about treesitter? I ended up configuring `nvim-treesitter` + `nvim-lspconfig` + `nvim-cmp`. Still reading the docs to understand how the last one differs from the other two

Comment: Well, I hope it helped. I heard about Treesitter but AFAIK it works best with Neovim nightly builds and I can't afford to use unstable IDE at work so I haven't tried it. I know its syntax highlighting is supposed to be superior so maybe it's worth to try some day soon. About other plugins, AFAIU current Neovim comes with its own LSP support (I probably should investigate and edit my answer) and `nvim-lspconfig` brings in config files for popular language servers. IDK why you'd need `nvim-cmp` - maybe it brings something that isn't built-in into Neovim already but if it does, IDK what it is.

Comment: @Breno Check this out (Neovim Kickstart): https://youtu.be/stqUbv-5u2s it seems to be using a setup similar to yours: Neovim's LSP, `nvim-cmp` and Treesitter. Uses very few plugins. I might steal some, e.g. Telescope looks awesome. I don't like that it's LUA (so won't work with VIM) but I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 15):

As Paul Tomblin mentioned you have to use **ctags**.
You could also consider using **plugins** to select appropriate one or to preview the definition of the function under cursor. 
Without plugins you will have a headache trying to select one of the hundreds overloaded 'doAction' methods as built in ctags support doesn't take in account the context - just a name.

Also you can use **cscope** and its 'find global symbol' function. But your vim have to be compiled with +cscope support which isn't default one option of build.

If you know that the function is defined in the current file, you can use 'gD' keystrokes in a normal mode to jump to definition of the symbol under cursor.

Here is the most downloaded plugin for navigation
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273

Here is one I've written to select context while jump to tag
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2507

Comment: Hi @mykola-golubyev , the link your provided in `Detailed description` section of `#2507` script is broken. Can you provide another one please?

Answer (score 14):

1- install exuberant ctags. If you're using osx, this article shows a little trick:
http://www.runtime-era.com/2012/05/exuberant-ctags-in-osx-107.html

2- If you only wish to include the ctags for the files in your directory only, run this command in your directory:

```
ctags -R
```

This will create a "tags" file for you.

3- If you're using Ruby and wish to include the ctags for your gems (this has been really helpful for me with RubyMotion and local gems that I have developed), do the following:

```
ctags --exclude=.git --exclude='*.log' -R * `bundle show --paths`
```

credit: https://coderwall.com/p/lv1qww
(Note that I omitted the -e option which generates tags for emacs instead of vim)

4- Add the following line to your ~/.vimrc

```
set autochdir 
set tags+=./tags;
```

(Why the semi colon: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Single_tags_file_for_a_source_tree )

5- Go to the word you'd like to follow and hit `ctrl + ]` ; if you'd like to go back, use `ctrl+o` (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53929/226255)

Comment: The link to the mentioned Mac article is broken.  Here is the updated link: http://runtime-era.blogspot.com/2012/05/exuberant-ctags-in-osx-107.html  Your best bet is to install ctags with a tool like Homebrew

Answer (score 13):

Another common technique is to place the function name in the first column. This allows the definition to be found with a simple search.

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
}
```

The above function could then be found with `/^main` inside the file or with `:grep -r '^main' *.c` in a directory. As long as code is properly indented the only time the identifier will occur at the beginning of a line is at the function definition.

Of course, if you aren't using **ctags** from this point on you should be ashamed of yourself! However, I find this coding standard a helpful addition as well.

Comment: I've always wondered why some coders write their signatures that way!

Comment: Also, when you write your function signatures, including '{' in the first column, you can move around quickly to each function by pressing ]] to go forward in the file and [[ to go backward.

Answer (score 7):

To second Paul's response: yes, ctags (especially exuberant-ctags (http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)) is great.  I have also added this to my vimrc, so I can use one tags file for an entire project:

```
set tags=tags;/
```

Answer (score 2):

Install `cscope`. It works very much like `ctags` but more powerful. To go to definition, instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>. Of course you may use both concurrently. But with a big project (say Linux kernel), cscope is miles ahead.

Answer (score 1):

After generating ctags, you can also use the following in vim:

```
:tag <f_name>
```

Above will take you to function definition.

Answer (score 1):

As @cprn has explained extensively, language servers are a top choice as they rarely find the wrong symbol.

So, forget about ctags.

Install [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe).
It's got auto-completion, jump-to-definition, refactoring and a whole lot more. Besides, it also supports C/C++, C#, Java, Rust, Go and others.