# Jump to function definition in vim, without using plugins or ctags

Tags: vim, function

is it possible to jump to function definitions in vim without using plugins or ctags?

and if so, how?

a related question:
[Jump to function definition in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635770/jump-to-function-definition-in-vim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were it possible, why would anybody write a plug-in or use `ctags`?

So let us assume that it is not.

You can use [<kbd>#</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html##) and [<kbd>*</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#star) to search backwards and forwards (respectively) for the word under your cursor in the current buffer.

Or you can use [`:vimgrep`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#%3avimgrep) and [<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W) to search for the word under the cursor in a given path.

Of course these match *words*, not function definitions, so they may match calls to a given function or variables with the same name. But that's th price you'd have to pay for not using `ctags`, I guess.

Comment: gd doesn't do anything when i try using it.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#gd - When the cursor is on a local **variable**, this command will jump to its declaration.

Comment: seems like it only works for local declarations. my declarations are located remotely.