# vim run perl script with word under cursor as argument

Tags: function, vim, arguments, shortcut, text-cursor

is it possible to send the word under the cursor to a perl script by typing a shortcut?

how do i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Above solutions are not safe if word under cursor contains special characters. You should use

```
nnoremap <F2> :execute "!/path/to/script.pl ".shellescape(expand("<cword>"), 1)<CR>
```

instead.

For the whole line, replace `expand("<cword>")` with `getline('.')`. For the filename under cursor use `expand("<cfile>")`.

Answer (score 2):

Given a perl script `${HOME}/test.pl`, you could use:

```
:nnoremap <F2> :!${HOME}/test.pl <C-R><C-W><CR>
```

Then pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> would send the word under the cursor to your script.

As per my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913544/), [<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W) represents the word under the cursor.

See the following help topics in Vim to get you started with writing keyboard shortcuts:

- [`:help :nnoremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:nnoremap)
- [`:help :map-special-keys`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-special-keys)
- [`:help !`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#!Blockquote)

My test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
print "You selected '$ARGV[0]'.\n";
```

Comment: and what represents the whole line under the cursor?

Comment: ZyX's answer better explains how to do this. I'm leaving my answer up here as it has some useful links as to how to map keys (and you've asked a few questions about this now).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
nnoremap <f5> :!perl my_script.pl <c-r><c-w><enter>
```

In your vimrc, this lines maps the F5 key to this combination of characters. CTRL-R CTRL-W inserts current word in a command line.