# "How can I jump to functions in a C++ project with vi

Tags: c++, function, vi

I am making a c++ program with vi. It has only one file but it's getting kind of big. It would be nice if I could easily see all the functions I created and jump to any one of them without having to search for them. Can vi do this, or is there a similar program that can?

Comment: BTW, a better title for this question would be "How can I jump to functions in a C++ project with vi or something similar?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a dup of [Jump to function definition in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635770/jump-to-function-definition-in-vim).

To sum up that answer, use ctags, and take a look at [Vim and Ctags tips and tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks).

Comment: ...and, of course, refactor that bad boy into smaller files :)

Answer (score 1):

I use a vim plugin to do this :

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273

It summarizes classes, struct, function, with jump functionality.