# using vim as a c++11 IDE

Tags: c++, vim, c++11, intellij-idea

I have been setting up my development environment in Vim for a while now. Since all my projects are in C++11 I have found some plugins that made my life easier and almost as good as the days of Intellij and Java. However there are still some things missing.

The main feature I miss is the refactoring utilities (rename across project, refactor code into functions/classes, remove classes, ...). Any recommendations on how I can get such functionality in vim?

I am using the following plugins:

---

gmarik/vundle
  Valloric/YouCompleteMe
  a.vim
  wincent/Command-T
  DoxygenToolkit.vim
  scrooloose/nerdtree
  godlygeek/tabular
  tpope/vim-sensible
  tpope/vim-unimpaired
  tpope/vim-endwise
  tpope/vim-fugitive
  jeffkreeftmeijer/vim-numbertoggle
  Lokaltog/vim-easymotion
  rstacruz/sparkup'
  Mizuchi/STL-Syntax

---

If you want the full details, here is my .vimrc (feel free to contribute to it in the gist):

https://gist.github.com/MauricioCarneiro/9547864

Comment: Honestly, why not hack up your own? Good learning experience. Maybe pick up the project mentioned in romainl's answer and bring it up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will need `Ultisnips`, `Tagbar` and `tcomment` plugin, especially `Ultisnips`.

More information about configuration, please refer:https://github.com/xautjzd/dotvim

Comment: good recommendations. I was curious why you use Ultisnips but not honza/vim-snippets in your .vimrc?

Answer (score 4):

In my plugins suites, you'll found:

- [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) (various things dedicated to C++)
- [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets) (smart insertions of brackets, surrounding, ...)
- [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/), with advanced C++ aware templates and snippets
- a [local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) plugin to help define projects
- [BuildWrapperTools](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper) that

  - wraps calls to make,
  - provides filters to compilers outputs (to add STLfilt on the fly for instance),
  - permits to switch between debug/Release/whatever configuration (for projects under CMake) ; example [here](https://github.com/LucHermitte/Rasende)
- [lh-refactor](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-refactor) (generic refactoring suite)

On github, I also have an [experimental project](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-clang) to wrap clang-indexer.

Answer (score 1):

The only refactoring tool for c++11 I know of is [clang-modernize](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-modernize.html) from LLVM and Intel guys ([Chandler Carruth from Google gave a speech](http://youtu.be/JSjoCisIHcM) about it on youtube). You can run it from vim as any other cli tool, e.g.:

```
:!clang-modernize -style=Google -format -loop-convert -pass-by-value -replace-auto_ptr -use-nullptr -use-auto -add-override -override-macros %
```

The `%` sign at the end will expand to your current file's path. There's more tools available nowadays, like `clangtidy` and `cquery`.

You can probably make all fixers and linters auto correct your code as you type with something like [ALE vim plugin](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#faq-c-configuration). Alternatively (and this is my preferred solution) you could use a [dedicated language server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635770/jump-to-function-definition-in-vim/51195409#51195409) and [coc.nvim plugin](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) which allows for a full IDE experience (with code specific fixers, snippets, jump to definition, find all interface implementations, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

[Refactor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2087) is the only C++ refactoring plugin on vim.org. Its latest update is from 2007, though, so I'm not sure it will work for C++11.

You could also try [Eclim,](http://eclim.org/) an Eclipse/Vim plugin that lets you use [a number of Eclipse features](http://eclim.org/features.html) from Vim.

Comment: Anyway, Vim is a text editor, not an IDE. If you need an IDE, use one.

Comment: Most of my plugins are dedicated to C++, and lh-refactor, while perfectible, supports C++.