# Jump to a search location in vim?

Tags: vim

When using vim, I often use the command `/foo` to jump to some variable `foo` in a file to look at it. I then remember the line number, press escape and then do `:lno` to jump to the line number. Is there an easy way to escape search so that my cursor is located at `foo` (without remembering the line number)?

This question is similar but not write right, as there may be multiple instances of `foo` in my file. [Jump to function definition in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635770/jump-to-function-definition-in-vim)

Comment: Do you have `:set hls` on? After executing a search, you can use `n` and `p` to navigate through hits? Or you could use `*` and `#` for forward and backward search of the current word under cursor.

Comment: hit enter instead of escape?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you press `<Esc>` to begin with?

Just press `<CR>` to put the cursor on `foo`:

```
/{pattern}[/]<CR>    Search forward for the [count]'th occurrence of
                     {pattern} |exclusive|.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [marks](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_03.html#03.10). Mark your current cursor position with a command like `ma` (where `a` is the name of the mark) and return to it with the command `a or `'a`. List marks with the command:

```
:marks
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vim, `<CR>` refers to the "Carriage Return" key, which is essentially the Enter or Return key on your keyboard.

So the sequence for jumping to the fist instance of `foo`: [Esc] -> `/foo` -> [Enter] -> `i`

In case you need 3rd instance of `foo`: [Esc] -> `/foo` -> [Enter] -> `n` -> `n` -> `n` -> `i`

General pattern:

1. enter command mode by pressing Esc
2. search with `/`, e.g. type in `/foo` in your case
3. press Enter to jump to the first found result
4. navigate b/w searches with `n` (forward), `N` backwards
5. enter the edit mode with pressing `i` while in command mode