# VIM "go to definition" functionality for Python

Tags: python, vim, ide

I want to use VIM as my IDE but it lacks the functionality of "go to definition" that other IDEs have (e.g. PyCharm).

This functionality offers to go to the definition of a function or variable with `ctrl+click`. I do not care how the functionality will be invoked (e.g. instead of `ctrl+click` could be `ctrl+q` or any other combination of keys/actions) but I really want to have it.

The fact that VIM lacks this is the main reason that I'm only using it when I'm editing files on a server and when I'm working from home (otherwise, git push/pull and the problem is solved).

Does anyone knows how to have this "go to definition" functionality in VIM?

Comment: Have you looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635770/jump-to-function-definition-in-vim) ?