# Vim: Move cursor to its last position

Tags: vim

Is it possible in (g)Vim to move the cursor to its previous position (while in normal mode)? Something to cycle back and forth in the list of previous cursor positions would be ideal. But also just to switch to the last location would suffice (something like `cd -` in bash with directories).

Here's a little demonstration:

```
line |1| <- cursor position
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

And suppose I did `2j`, here's how it is now:

```
line 1
line 2
line |3| <- cursor position
line 4
```

Now I'd like to press something (other than `2k` obviously) to move back to the first position and possibly to previous positions.

Answer (score 518, accepted):

The quickest way is to hit either:

<kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>

(two apostrophes) or:

<kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>

(two backticks).  Note that the difference is that the backtick goes to the same location on the line, whereas the apostrophe goes to the start of the line.  On a UK keyboard, the apostrophe is more accessible, so I tend to use that one.  There are loads of useful marks like this, see `:help mark-motions`.

For some other motions (not <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> I think), there's also the jump-list that lets you navigate back and forth among a number of motions.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> do this navigation, but see `:help jump-motions` for more information.

Comment: actually none of those behave exactly like I expect but I guess there isn't anything else available.

Comment: @Idan K - how does `` (double backtick) not give you exactly what you want?  (Except for the "history" aspect).

Comment: @Dan: if I try it on the example above then I see this behavior: I stand on line 1, then press `j` twice in a row (now I'm on line 3) then pressing double backtick gets to me line 1 and I expect it to move to line 2.

Comment: I think you have to move (2j or something), then edit (or make any action to modify the text) then use '' to move back to the previous position. That is not logical to use "2j" , do nothing and go back to the previous position

Comment: @IdanK The jumplist is only updated (i.e. the previous cursor position is recorded) when you use an actual "jump," which is (I think) any motion command other than the `i j k l` movements. (The complete list, from the help docs, is `"'"', "\`", "G", "/", "?", n", "N", "%", "(", ")", "[[", "]]", "{", "}", ":s", ":tag", "L", "M", H" and the commands that start editing a new file`.) So no, this won't "undo" `2j` or similar, but it will work for almost everything else. This makes sense because `2j` et al. already have simple inversions (`2k`, etc), while the others do not.

Comment: @Asenar, it has nothing to do with modifying the text, which makes sense because you might want to use the jumplist without needing to modify the buffer (let alone the file itself!).

Comment: It's worth noting the jumplist is also updated on executing ex commands that move the cursor (e.g., `.t+5` copies the current line 5 lines forward and moves the cursor to that new line).

Comment: This does not seem to work when I do lets say `f,` to find a comma; what then?

Answer (score 85):

You can also use `g;` and `g,` to move back- and forward in the list of your previous **edit** locations.

### On Non-US Keyboards

On my Swiss and German keyboard layouts, typing `;` inconveniently requires using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. Hence, I defined `g-` as a more convenient alias for `g;` in `$MYVIMRC`:

```
" Map g- as an alias for g;
nnoremap g- g;
```

Comment: While I like this a lot, it only will jump between changes in one file. If you edit buffer 1, then edit buffer 2, it won't jump back to buffer 1.

Answer (score 75):

Why no one figured out the problem with [DrAl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052103/8554766)?
The <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> will not solve the original problem of this post! 
These two command will not work for some cursor movement like <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>, at least for me. It will make newbie to vim more confused.

The behavior of  <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> are based on jump list. The <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> will not save the position changes into the jump list so these command will not work for <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>.

<kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> switch between the last position and the current position.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> work through the jump list history.

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> move through edit positions, which are also very frequently used.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I wonder, what will work for cases like `2j`, then?

Comment: Thanks @ZhaoGang, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Not every movement needs something fancy.  If I 2j and want to go back I can say 2k   :)

Answer (score 37):

Right from the help (:help jump):

> :ju[mps]       Print the jump list (not a motion command).  {not in
>                 Vi} {not available without the |+jumplist| feature}
>
> ```
>                           *jumplist*
> ```
>
> Jumps are remembered in a jump list.  With the CTRL-O and CTRL-I command you
>      can go to cursor positions before older jumps, and back again.  Thus you can
>      move up and down the list.  There is a separate jump list for each window.
>      The maximum number of entries is fixed at 100.
>      {not available without the |+jumplist| feature}