# Vim go to ruby class declaration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vim

I want to follow from

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

to

```
/home/slavik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc6/lib/action_controller/base.rb
```

and look to commented reference of possible usage this class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is at least one way. You can use [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) in combination with the [tags](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27tags%27) option of Vim. Pratically, you have to execute ctags in the /home/slavik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ like :

```
ctags -R tags
```

See `ctags --help` if you want to dig into tags customization. Then you have to add this file to your tags path in vim. Using something like the following:

```
:set tag+=/home/slavik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/tags
```

In order to understand how powerful this vim features is take a look at [Browsing_programs_with_tags](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags).

Comment: "ctags -Rtags" is giving : "ctags: Unknown option: -t"

Comment: i tried `ctags -R --language-force=ruby --sort=yes` and it worked ; why should i pass `-Rtags` ? what does that mean ?

Comment: Ah I see! there was a problem with spaces. I updated the answer. thank you for noticing!

Comment: Actualy the parameter `tags` is interpreted as a `filename` as explained in the documentation !, and if it didn't exists it throws a file not found error

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of issues with ctags which has pretty old and ugly parser:

- Ctags doesn't deal with: module A::B
- Ctags doesn't tag (at least some of) the operator methods like ==
- Ctags doesn't support qualified tags, -type=+
- Ctags doesn't output tags for constants or attributes.

I would recommend better project **ripper-tags** based on *official* Ruby parser called Ripper which is included in Ruby. It is *fast and accurate*: https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags

You can also install **gem-ripper-tags** to have tags files automatically generated after gem installation: https://github.com/lzap/gem-ripper-tags

*Please note that these days, August 2013, there is a big refactoring of ripper-tags which can lead to change of command line options or gem-ripper-tags interface. If things are not working, update both gems in couple of days and read help screen to learn new options.*

Answer (score 1):

ripper-tags sounds great but is having issues as of today (November 2013). 
I ended up using exuberant ctags (with a few tricks)

1- install exuberant ctags. If you're using osx, this article shows a little trick:
http://www.runtime-era.com/2012/05/exuberant-ctags-in-osx-107.html

2- If you only wish to include the ctags for the files in your directory only, run this command in your directory:

```
ctags -R
```

This will create a "tags" file for you.

3- If you wish to include the ctags for your gems (this has been really helpful for me with RubyMotion and local gems that I have developed), do the following:

```
ctags --exclude=.git --exclude='*.log' -R * `bundle show --paths`
```

credit: https://coderwall.com/p/lv1qww
(Note that I removed the -e option which generates tags for emacs instead of vim)

4- Add the following line to your ~/.vimrc

```
set autochdir 
set tags+=./tags;
```

(Why the semi colon: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Single_tags_file_for_a_source_tree )

5- Go to the word you'd like to follow and hit `ctrl+]` . hit `ctrl+o` to go back (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53929/226255)